# SNMP get with SNMP version automatic (V1.0/V2.0)

Tags: c#-4.0, snmp, sharp-snmp

How to execute GET method for SNMP of OID without passing the SNMP version.

As in my case, some of the devices respond to V1.0 and some for V2.0.

I have come acrossed in OIDVIEW , there is a "Automatic" SNMP version rather than passing version.

I know V3.0 requires password and username. where as in the case of V1.0 and V2.0 it is just community.

```
public static string GetData(string ipaddress)
    {
        string community = "private", response = "";
        SimpleSnmp snmp = new SimpleSnmp(ipaddress, community);
        if (!snmp.Valid)
            response="ip address is invalid. -" + ipaddress;

        Dictionary<Oid, AsnType> result = snmp.Get(SnmpVersion.Ver2,
                                              new string[] { "1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0" });
        if (result == null)
            response=("No results received. -" + ipaddress);
        else
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<Oid, AsnType> kvp in result)
                response = kvp.Value.ToString();
        }

        return response;
    }
```

I'm expecting something like `SnmpVersion.Automatic` along with `SnmpVersion.Ver1 , Ver2 , Ver3`

Is there a solution using snmpsharpnet or any other components?

Answer (score 0):

If you spend some time on RFC documents such as RFC 3584,

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3584

you will see that even v1 and v2c differ.

#SNMP is designed to be low level library and it does not attempt to be an application level stuff such as OIDVIEW. No detail should be hidden from the users, and that's why there is no "automatic".

"Automatic" is something outside of SNMP RFC documents. OIDVIEW might define it as an algorithm that picks up the most suitable version for users, but I don't see a need that #SNMP to support such vendor defined behaviors.

You can check out snmpsharpnet or other components of course.